# Email confusion

Tags: support, user-accounts

So I wanted to know if I can change my email from one to another. What I mean is that I want to use the other email that I have other than the email I have already on the account. I just got a new professional email, but I want to change it. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Shouldn't the tag **(bug)** be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an email account to *display* by clicking on the "edit" button on the top of your profile page. If you want to merge two emails into one account, use the "my logins" button, as robjohn has said in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

On your profile page, there is an "edit" button that lets you edit the fields of your profile, one of which is email. If you want to change your login, there is a "my logins" button that allows you to change that.